# Laravel $request->expectsJson()

Tags: json, laravel, laravel-5, http-headers, content-type

I am doing an Ajax login for my Laravel application.

I am using Angular:

```
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: '/admin/login',
  headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  data: {email:$scope.email,password:$scope.password}
})
```

This request works fine, my problem is that Laravel's response always redirects me, as it should *if I wasn't sending JSON:*

```
protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
    {
        $errors = [$this->username() => trans('auth.failed')];
        if ($request->expectsJson()) {
            return response()->json($errors, 422);
        }
        return redirect()->back()
            ->withInput($request->only($this->username(), 'remember'))
            ->withErrors($errors);
    }
```

That is the Laravel framework code. It keeps redirected me back, but I want to fire the conditional `if ($request->expectsJson())` and get a JSON response rather than a redirect.

What am I missing in order to trigger that conditional?

I even added:

```
 headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json','X-Requested-With' :'XMLHttpRequest'
  }
```

And it still won't work.

[expectsJson()](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php#L704):

```
public function expectsJson()
    {
        return ($this->ajax() && ! $this->pjax()) || $this->wantsJson();
    }
```

My headers:

> Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
>
> Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
>
> Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
>
> Connection:keep-alive
>
> Content-Length:57
>
> Content-Type:application/json
>
> X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest

I'm not included tokens/cookies and the origin url for security reason, but they are in there.

Edit: I tried clearing the artisan cache and still nothing.

`php artisan cache:clear`

Also

`composer dump-autoload`

Comment: You must add `Accept` header as discribed [here](https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/100)

Comment: @Maraboc My Accept header is already `application/json, text/plain, */*`

Comment: is the user already logged in?! Guest middleware applied to all routes of AuthController, except the getLogout.
Hence, any ajax call to these routes it redirects to the home route

Comment: @Leo_Kelmendi No, I'm supplying incorrect credentials and am not logged in.

Comment: Can you give us the output of this `$request->expectsJson()` The condition is probably not true, so it skips that if and redirects back

Comment: @Leo_Kelmendi can you provide the proper way to do this then, without changing that middleware?

Comment: @Leo_Kelmendi Actually, I don't understand your comment. My reading of `RedirectIfAuthenticated` means that I wouldn't be redirected if the login fails?

Comment: @SummerDeveloper basically if u have a logged in user then any ajax request to the app will be redirected to home from middleware except logout. However I really don't understand why u would want an ajax call to login a user ?!  You would still have to refresh the page, or redirect to show the appropriate content to the just authorized user. So, I don't think Ajax is going to be effective at this particular situation

Comment: @Leo_Kelmendi I'm not logged in though! The ajax login should work! Also, there are ways to elegantly load authenticated content without a redirect in Angular.

Comment: and I think your condition should be:  if ($request->ajax()) {
            return response()->json($errors, 422);
        }

Comment: @Leo_Kelmendi It's framework code... I don't believe I should edit it unless it's a bug in Laravel that should be reported?

Comment: yeah it's the framework code... but designed to be used with POST/GET thats why on ur case u have to edit for ajax()

Comment: @Leo_Kelmendi I don't think that's correct, I think `expectsJson()` explicitly checks for ajax.

Comment: okay thanks for sharing ur thoughts. Have u tried changing routes to see if its a framework bug which I believe its not since the redirect back issue was resolved after laravel 5.1

Comment: It seems to me that something is missing in your frontend request, can you please show us the header's request from the browser's console ?

Comment: @OuailB edited.

Answer (score 50):

You should use `Accept` key not `Content/type`. For more details, check [this github discussion](https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/100#issuecomment-248917207)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just use `$request->isJson()` for `'Content-type': 'application/json'` in laravel 10