# Laravel restful api for existing system

Tags: php, laravel, rest, api, routes

Hie Guys i have a Laravel Application that i have build. I want to create an API without rewriting the methods and controllers etc. Fore example i have routes/web.php that returns a view with a list of practitioners and display in a table.

```
Route::get('/admin/practitioners', 'PractitionersController@index');
```

Now i want to use the same method and same controller to create an API that returns json data not a view without creating a new controller and methods.
This is my method index in PractitionersController

```
 public function index()
    {
        $practitioners = Practitioner::whereApproval_status(1)->get()->sortBy('first_name');
        $pendings = Practitioner::whereApproval_status(0)->get()->sortBy('first_name');
        return view('admin.practitioners.index', compact('practitioners', 'pendings'));
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel $request->expectsJson()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015586/laravel-request-expectsjson)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use api.php in routes directory. Then check if request come from api like this:

```
if (Request::wantsJson()) {
    // return JSON
} else {
    // return view
}
```

or check if you don't want multiple response type (xml, json..)

```
if( $request->is('api/*'))
```